# can I sign an unlimited contract with a company in Vancouver, BC,and continue working remotely for a foreign firm as a contractor?

Tags: contract-law, canada, labor-law

I'm an Indian national working in NZ as a contractor at the moment.

I've been offered an "unlimited contract" by a Vancouver, BC, Canada based firm which I've signed. The work permit is on its way and I'm expecting to relocate to Vancouver soon.

My question is can I still LEGALLY continue to remotely work as a contactor for my NZ based company?

Is this illegal in any shape or form or if it's not, am I expected to tell the authorities explicitly and pay taxes on it in Canada?

Are there any other gotchas I might need to be aware of just in case?

Can this impact my permanent residency domination in the future in any way?

Thanks in advance for all the answers!